# How do I get RadioSelect to iterate over each choice for specific field when I write them in manually?

Tags: python-3.x, django-models, django-forms

I have a model in which I am gathering contact information for potential customers.  One of these pertains to the month and I am trying to get them to display as a Radio Button.  I used the RadioSelect option only to find out there is no Radio button attached with it.

I found how to manually input each field of a form into a page using the Django Documentation.  I did this and it worked, but it is now displaying all 12 months, 12 times over.  I don't know how to make it show all 12 months just one time.

**forms.py**

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django import forms
from .models import CustomerData, Ebook

MONTH_CHOICES = [
    ('January', 'January'),
    ('February', 'February'),
    ('March','March'),
    ('April', 'April'),
    ('May', 'May'),
    ('June','June'),
    ('July', 'July'),
    ('August', 'August'),
    ('September','September'),
    ('October','October'),
    ('November','November'),
    ('December','December')
]


class ContactForm(ModelForm):
    month = forms.ChoiceField(label='', choices=MONTH_CHOICES, widget=forms.RadioSelect(), error_messages={'required' : 'Month is Required'})
    phone = forms.CharField(required=False)
    firstname = forms.CharField(label='', error_messages={'required': 'First Name Required'})
    lastname = forms.CharField(label='', error_messages={'required': 'Last Name Required'})
    npo = forms.CharField(label='', error_messages={'required': 'Organization Required'})
    email = forms.CharField(label='', error_messages={'required': 'Email Required'})
    class Meta:
        model = CustomerData
        fields = ['firstname', 'lastname', 'npo', 'email', 'phone', 'month']
```

**index.html**

```
<div class="fieldWrapper">
        {{ form.month.errors }}
<label for="{{ form.subject.id_for_label }}">Month:</label>
    {% for month in form.month %}
        <label>
         <input name="group1" type="radio" />
         <span> {{ form.month }} </span>
        </label>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

I need this to iterate over the months and display each of them just one time

**This is an image of what I am seeing**

[image: 12 months 12 times]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disregard. I figured it out.  Here is the solution for anyone who might stumble upon this one.

```
    <!-- Month -->
<div class="fieldWrapper">
        {{ form.month.errors }}
<label for="{{ form.subject.id_for_label }}">Month:</label>
<br>
    {% for month, monthb in form.fields.month.choices %}
        <label>
         <input name="group1" type="radio" />
         <span> {{month}} </span>
        </label>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

I needed to have two references and call only one of them in the span section.  I also needed to add the choices to the for loop initialization.